# how to force a c program to run on a particular core

Tags: c, process, cpu-cores

Say I have the following c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world \n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

gcc 1.c -o helloworld
```

and, say I have a dual core machine:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
```

Now my question is, when we execute the program, how do we force this program to run in core-0 (or any other particular core)?

How to do this programmatically? examples, api's, code reference would be helpful.

If there is no api's available then is there any compile time, link time, load time way of doing this?

OTOH, how to check whether a program is running in core-0 or core-1 (or any other core)?

Comment: This is not in the scope of C. You have to check your operating system's documentation to see if the OS exposes such a feature.

Comment: Under Linux you can set affinity using taskset, also I agree with Kerrek that this is more an operation system question

Comment: While you can use taskset to set the core affinity of a launched process afterwards, he clearly asks for an api and how to do it programmatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are talking about /proc/cpu, I assume you are using linux. In linux you would use the `sched_setaffinity` function. In your example you would call

```
cpu_set_t set;
CPU_ZERO(&set);        // clear cpu mask
CPU_SET(0, &set);      // set cpu 0
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set);  // 0 is the calling process
```

Look up `man sched_setaffinity` for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This is OS-specific.  As Felice points out, you can do it on Linux by calling [sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) in your program.  If you end up running on multiple platforms, though, you'll have to code something different for each.

Alternatively, you can specify the affinity when you *launch* your executable, from the command line or a run script or whatever.
See [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) for a Linux command-line tool to do this.