# make a c++ program run on a specific core in windows

Tags: c++, windows, cpu-cores

I was wondering how to force a program in C++ in Visual Studio, to run on specific core/cores (on computers that have more than one).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326427/how-to-force-a-c-program-to-run-on-a-particular-core/) article, but it refers to C in Linux (and I am using Visual Studio on Windows)

Also, does the Windows version I'm using, matter?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [SetProcessAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: what i understood from this link is that: 1) it is not possible to choose a specific core in windows, and `affinity mask` is a tool to control it by little, even though eventually the operating system makes the call. 2) it could only be made in threads. this concept does not make sense to me, because i heard graphic programs that lets the user choose cores specifically to render their programs.

Comment: @yd1 The previous comments should be correct. If you only want to _suggest_ a specific core use [SetThreadIdealProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686253(v=vs.85).aspx) if you'd like Windows to decide for you. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684251(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information on the difference between the two options.

Comment: thank you! please write a formal answer so i can accept it and it would be less confusing when i would read it again, and for other users. i think that `SetProcessAffinityMask` and `SetThreadIdealProcessor` are the most fit to the topic.

Comment: Just a thaught: in UNIX there are the commands `pbind` or `psrset` for forcing an executable to run on a specific core. Maybe there are similar commands in Windows and the solution is not inside the program, but in the way to start it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to use the Windows API function [`SetThreadIdealProcessorEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405517(v=vs.85).aspx).  This function is applicable to Windows 7 or later.   On older systems, it is possible to use [`SetThreadIdealProcessor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686253(v=vs.85).aspx), albeit with some more limitations.

This, according to remarks at the first link

> Specifying a thread ideal processor provides a hint to the scheduler about the preferred processor for a thread. The scheduler runs the thread on the thread's ideal processor when possible.

I'm not aware of any function that forces the scheduler to run a thread on a specified processor.   So giving a hint, which the scheduler will attempt to act on, is probably the closest you can get to meeting your requirement.

It would probably be advisable to also use [`SetProcessorAffinityMask()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx) as well, which works to specify processors on which a process may run, since it would seem unlikely that a thread can run on a processor that is not within its parent process's affinity mask.

Read the documentation for these functions carefully, because the system itself can impose limits on which processors a process may run.