# Lock CPU resources in production critical applications (safety overhead)

Tags: c#, c++, resources, cpu, overhead

When coding an app for Windows (c++, c#), is there a way to lock a certain amount of cpu percentage or cores or threads so they cannot be used by other programs or processes when said app is running? I know you could tinker with CPU priority and affinity in task manager, but I don't know if that prevents other programs to 'steal' cpu power when they need it.

The app is very cpu intensive and dependant on 'real time' operation so when the usage reaches 100%, cpu cannot deal with all the load and errors occur.

So ideally the code would make sure that, if the app is currently working nicely and using 80% of the cpu, no other proccess would ever be allowed to take the remaining 20% (allowing only 10% usage, for example). I guess you could call that 'safety overhead'?  I hope I made myself clear.

I am trying to figure out if such a concept exists at all, I couldn't be sure of the keywords or find a thread to start pulling.
If that is not possible in Windows c++ c#, is it a thing in other enviroments?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows is not a real time OS. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: The concept is called "real-time". Windows does have some real-time features. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multimedia-class-scheduler-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Can you tell us what the app does, and what happens if the CPU is too slow? Does the app play sounds so it would like to avoid annoying laggy stuttering sounds? Or does it control industrial robots that could kill people?

Comment: Fortunately, the app is in the video broadcast sector, so no one would die if the CPU goes up to 100%. I guess some people could lose their minds if the recordings drop frames and some information is lost, but I think they can recover from that no problem!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you : Set process affinity mask : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068025/make-a-c-program-run-on-a-specific-core-in-windows

Comment: You can [set the thread priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority), but you risk starving essential Windows services of CPU. I certainly wouldn't advise higher than `High` except in very specific circumstances, and only with a short-running task. `Real time` is highly dangerous and can completely lock up your machine.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no nice way of doing such things, especially since what you are trying to use is a custom scheduler, but as these are usually hard-coded into the operating system I don't see much hope for you.

If real-time functionality is your main concern, I would either recommend using a real-time-operating-system or optimizing your software, so it doesn't need 80% of your CPU, if possible. You could also just upgrade your CPU (if money is not really a concern), so it can handle your software.

Under other operating systems there are ways to encourage the scheduler to like your software more (look up "nice value") but that's similar to changing priority in Task Manager (on steroids however).

I also remember from my operating systems lecture that there are operating systems that allow the scheduler to be modified, this might be further than you wanted to go, but that is a possibility if you become desperate enough.

And as my last idea: If you have something really computationally intense, it is often doing something over and over again. Assuming that these steps are (partially) independent of each other, it could be a massive performance gain to move work from the CPU to the GPU, from my experience (n=1) saving 50% is possible. From C++ with an Nvidia GPU you want to look up CUDA, for everything else you likely want OpenCL.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, using the GPU is something that we should look into, and hopefully can be done in the near future. Switching to a non-widespread OS is definitely a scary thought, but if it ensures that the proccess will not be compromised by a rogue antivirus that decided it was time to scan everything or something like that... For now we send overkill CPUs whenever we can. It's the only way to play it safe.

Comment: @Sidonai you might want to investigate the Linux real-time kernel.